# Native Ubuntu VM from Ubuntu

Tags: command-line

I know there is a way to make mini Ubuntu VMs from the command line in Ubuntu, but I cannot for the life of me remember what that is called.  Google search doesnt return results as I cant think of the name.  Is this ringing a bell with anyone?

Comment: [Sorry cant comment, try this](https://codepre.com/how-to-use-mini-iso-to-perform-a-clean-ubuntu-20-04-or-18-04-installation-via-unity.html) .

Comment: Are you thinking about LXC/LXD?  They'll make containers of Ubuntu systems but they aren't VMs per-se, and don't have GUIs by default.  Are you expecting this to create tiny server CLI-only VMs accessible by the shell or are you expecting these to be full blown GUI included systems?

Comment: A Docker container might be considered a "Mini Ubuntu VM" ... but many containers will go with Alpine Linux instead, which is better suited for smaller container sizes 

Comment: @ThomasWard It is a shell only service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! Multipass was created by Canonical so it works really well and feels native  https://multipass.run/